# Deserialization of a singleton object

Tags: java, serialization, singleton

Hi i'm trying to find a way to serialize and deserialize a singleton object while retrieving the object that was serialized before e.g: after I want to add doctors to my hospital object and after it being deserialized i get my doctors list back.
I read that in order to serialize a singleton I need to add **readResolve()** method.
but still every time i rebuild my object I'm getting new instance and it's empty, although i'm not getting any errors

```
public class Hospital implements Serializable{

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private static  Hospital theHospital = null;


   private HashMap<Integer, Doctor> doctors;
   private HashMap<Integer, Nurse> nurses;
   private HashMap<Integer, PatientReport> reports;
   private HashMap<Integer, Patient> patients;
   private HashMap<Integer, Patient> hotelPatients;
   private HashMap<Integer, Disease> diseases;
   private HashMap<Integer, Department> departments;
   private HashMap<String,Department> departmentsByName;
   private HashMap<Patient, HashSet<Doctor>> doctorsList;
   private HashMap<Patient, HashSet<Nurse>> nursesList;
   private TreeMap<Integer, Nurse> nurseShiftSet;
   private  ArrayList<SubDepartment> subSet;
   private HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Doctor>> docUser;
   private HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Nurse>> nurseUser;

   private TreeSet<Department> DepList;


   public static Hospital getInstance() {
               if (theHospital == null){
                      theHospital = new Hospital();
               }
               return theHospital;

   }
```

this is the object **getInstance()**

and here is the methods that i have used to write and read the serialized file .

```
    private static ObjectInputStream input; 
    
    public static void writeObject(Hospital h) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("Hospital.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            out.writeObject(h);
            out.close();
            file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in creating the file");
        }
    }
    public static Hospital readObject() {

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("Hospital.ser");
            input = new ObjectInputStream(file);
            Hospital h = (Hospital) input.readObject();
            file.close();
            input.close();
            return h;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

*****Update*****

Example :

```
Hospital h = Hospital.getInstance();
Department department = new Department("department name");
HashMap<String,Department> map = h.getDepartmentsByName();

// adding the department to the hospital instance .
map.put(department.getName(),department); 

Serializing.writeObject(h); // writing the given instance h.

map.remove(d.getName());
// removing from the current instance after serializing.

h = Serializing.readObject(); // deserializing from the file.

map =  h.getDepartmentsByName();



map.get(d.getName);// i'm expecting to return the department d , but it returns null.
```

Comment: Use the `readResolve()` method in `Hospital`.

Answer (score 0):

Use object-mappers. Also your question doesn’t explain what exactly you are looking for. Share some examples of the same to explain the problem. Also, serialize and deserialise doesn’t seem right the way you are doing.

Comment: I added an example , what is the wrong with serializing methods?